# Firebase Phone Authentication using Flutter

Tags: android, xcode, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Hi Im new in flutter and trying to use firebase phone authentication by using flutter. however, when I try to press the button, I get the following error.
I am using AndroidStudio.

```
Xcode build done.                                           21.5s
    path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0
Configuring the default Firebase app...
Configured the default Firebase app __FIRAPP_DEFAULT.
    path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0
Syncing files to device iPhone 11 Pro Max...
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c7127e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff513fbb20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c710bc +[NSException raise:format:] + 188
    3   Runner                              0x0000000103e97d81 -[FIRPhoneAuthProvider verifyPhoneNumber:UIDelegate:completion:] + 193
    4   Runner                              0x000000010440dc3d -[FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] + 18109
    5   Flutter                             0x000000010600ddb5 __45-[FlutterMethodChannel setMethodCallHandler:]_block_invoke + 104
    6   Flutter                             0x0000000105fa1ba0 _ZNK7flutter21PlatformMessageRouter21HandlePlatf<…>
Lost connection to device.
```

This is my code. Please someone help me

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),

//      initialRoute: '/',
//      routes: {
//        '/' : (context) => WelcomeClass(),
//        '/LoginClass' : (context) => LoginClass(),
//        '/SignUpClass' : (context) => SignUpClass(),
//      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String phoneNo;
  String smsCode;
  String verificationId;

  Future<void> verifyPhone() async {
    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout autoRetrieve = (String verId) {
      this.verificationId = verId;
    };

    final PhoneCodeSent smsCodeSent = (String verId, [int forceCodeResend]) {
      this.verificationId = verId;
      smsCodeDialog(context).then((value){
        print('signed in');
      });
    };

    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationSuccess = (AuthCredential user){
      print('Phone Verification Completed');
    };

    final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed =
        (AuthException exception) {
      print('${exception.message}');
    };

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: this.phoneNo,
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: autoRetrieve,
      codeSent: smsCodeSent,
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 60),
      verificationCompleted: verificationSuccess,
      verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
    );
  }

  Future<bool> smsCodeDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return new AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Enter sms code'),
            content: TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                this.smsCode = value;
              },
            ),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Done'),
                onPressed: () {
                  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
                    if (user != null) {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      Navigator.of(context)
                          .pushReplacementNamed('/SignUpClass');
                    } else {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      signIn();
                    }
                  });
                },
              )
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  signIn() {
    final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
        verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: smsCode);

    FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential).then((user) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');
    }).catchError((e) {
      print('Auth Credential Error : $e');
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(38.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                this.phoneNo = value;
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 40,
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text("Send code"),
              onPressed: verifyPhone,
            ), //FlatButton
          ], // Widget
        ),
      ), // Column
    );
  }
}
```

I feel that there is something wrong with the flutter I installed. 
Ive also tried to run on my real phone but it crashed too.